# AWS Inline Policy to Limit Automation Document Execution per IAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-systems-manager

AWS Inline Policy to Limit Automation Document Execution per IAM is my goal, but understanding current limitations I can see that I can only use `*` wildcard and can't specify a specific document.

Is there any way to limit specific IAM to only have access over specific automation documents.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "test",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssm:StartAutomationExecution"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Are you wanting to grant permission to only execute a specific document?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JohnRotenstein, @HenrikPingel, I have found a way to achieve what I wanted with

```
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
  {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
      "ssm:*"
    ],
    "Resource": [
      "arn:aws:ssm:eu-west-2:{accountnumberplaceholder}:automation-definition/{documentnameplaceholder}:$DEFAULT",
      "arn:aws:ssm:eu-west-2:{accountnumberplaceholder}:automation-definition/{documentnameplaceholder}:$DEFAULT",
      "arn:aws:ssm:eu-west-2:{accountnumberplaceholder}:automation-definition/{documentnameplaceholder}:$DEFAULT",
      "arn:aws:ssm:eu-west-2:{accountnumberplaceholder}:*",
      "arn:aws:ec2:eu-west-2:{accountnumberplaceholder}:instance/*",
      "arn:aws:ssm:eu-west-2::document/AWS-RunPowerShellScript"
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can limit IAM permissions by specifying the ARN of the document in the resource field.
The ARN for AWS Systems Manager is [contructed](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/auth-and-access-control-iam-access-control-identity-based.html#arn-formats) as follows:

```
arn:aws:ssm:region:account-id:document/document-name
```

You can specify the full arn of the document or place the asterix in the arn to limit the permission to a subset of the documents. Like in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/auth-and-access-control-permissions-reference.html):

```
arn:aws:ssm:us-west-2:111222333444:document:West*
```

Comment: Unfortunately, my testing seems to indicate that it is not possible to provide an ARN of an Automation Document when specifying the `ssm:StartAutomationExecution` action. It seems to only work with `Resource: *`. Did you manage to get a policy working with a specific ARN?

Comment: Can you please provide the error message you are getting? As stated I took the example from the the official documentation. Can you check if `arn:aws:ssm:us-west-2:111222333444:document/West*` (note the `/` instead if `:`) works? I'm not 100% sure if that could be it, but it is worth a try.

Comment: I could not get it to work. IAM says "This policy does not grant any permissions". The error message says `not authorized to perform: ssm:StartAutomationExecution on resource: arn:aws:ssm:ap-southeast-2:123456789012:automation-definition/foo:$DEFAULT`. If you get it working, please let us know the policy that you used.

Comment: The documentation is very unclear and the above suggestions are not working, but they may work for other documents, I am not sure.